# Symfony app theming best practice

Tags: symfony, theming, symfony-3.3

Still learning Symfony.
I've a generic theme based on bootstrap bought to be applied on our application.
This theme contains javascripts, less/css files, images and fonts.

I'm using assetic and i'm trying to figure which is the best practice of including this theme in the application.

Should i put all the files in a subfolder of app\Resources\public?

```
app/Resources/public/mytheme 
app/Resources/public/mytheme/css 
app/Resources/public/mytheme/js
app/Resources/public/mytheme/images
```

But then, especially for images, i'd have to refer to files in twig by something like

```
{% image '../app/Resources/public/mytheme/images/user/no-image.png' output="images/user/no-image.png"%} 
    <img src="{{ asset_url }}" alt="Example"/>
{% endimage %}
```

It doesn't install any symlink or asset by using

```
php bin/console asset:install --symlink
```

And in a css i have the ".logo" class that has a reference to "app/Resources/public/mytheme/images/theme-logo.png" that in html results in a broken link even with a cssrewrite filter.

Should i create a MyThemeBundle that contains all the assets? Or should i put all the assets in web/mytheme folder (but all the assets will be public even less files)?

I'm a bit confused.

Answer (score 1):

Fully read this page :
http://symfony.com/doc/current/assetic/asset_management.html#including-css-stylesheets

for an understanding about how to use the cssrewrite filter, to correctly point to your images, from inside your css